# Adding a new constructor to my ParentDetail class?

Tags: c#

This is a follow up to my previous question. I took the advice of a member and everything works. But now when I want to have another constructor I have a problem I didn't have before. Here's what I have now:

```
   public class Parent {

    public Parent() { this._parentDetails = new List<ParentDetail>(); }
    public IList<ParentDetail> ParentDetails { get { return _parentDetails; } }
    private List<ParentDetail> _parentDetails; // = new List<ParentDetail>();

    public Parent(int count) {
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ParentDetails.Add(new ParentDetail{ 
            Id = i + 1 
      } );
    }
```

When I call the class with a number as in "Parent(int count)" then it fails and tells me the instance of ParentDetails is null. Do I have to make it so that the default constructor is called or will I need to manually create an instance of ParentDetail within the new constructor?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
public Parent(int count) : this() {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ParentDetails.Add(new ParentDetail{ 
            Id = i + 1 
        } );
    }
}
```

Calling `new()` invokes the default constructor. If you wanted to call the `Parent(int count)` constructor from the `Parent()` constructor (for example with a default value for `count`), you could similarly call `this(1)`.

If you were doing this in an inherited class, you could call `base()`.

As a rule of thumb I would suggest that you put as much as possible in one constructor that can take all the possible arguments, then have other constructors that take fewer arguments and supply default values, call it.

E.g.:

```
public Parent() : this(5) {  }

public Parent(int count) : this() {
    this._parentDetails = new List<ParentDetail>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ParentDetails.Add(new ParentDetail{ 
            Id = i + 1 
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: @mdm You mean I should actually put the words new(); there where you put them? That gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Yes I know, it has been edited... First thing in the morning is not the best time to answer questions -_-

Comment: @mdm - Good morning to you :-) Thanks for the edits. You had a couple of vote downs. I'll accept this answer as you were the first.

Answer (score 1):

You can do either one of these two options that you mentioned

I think calling the default constructor is a little better, because you might add more stuff to it later and it will be automatically reflected, plus it reduces redundency of code:

```
public Parent(int count) : this() {
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    ParentDetails.Add(new ParentDetail{ 
        Id = i + 1 
  }
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of this. The other user gave an example but I think wrong language :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
public Parent(int count):this() {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ParentDetails.Add(new ParentDetail{ 
        Id = i + 1 
    } );
}
```